# Symfony 4 AdminLTE template not working properly

Tags: symfony, adminlte

I am trying to implement AdminLTE for the AdminCP of my website in Symfony 4. I performed these steps:

1. Ran `composer require kevinpapst/adminlte-bundle ^2.0`
2. Ran `cp vendor/kevinpapst/adminlte-bundle/config/packages/admin_lte.yaml config/packages/`
3. Added `.addEntry('adminlte', './assets/js/adminlte.js')` to `webpack.config.js`
4. Modified `package.json` so it looks like:

This

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "~5.1.1",
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.27.0",
        "admin-lte": "~2.4.8",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "bootstrap-select": "^1.13.1",
        "daterangepicker": "^3.0.3",
        "icheck": "^1.0.2",
        "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "core-js": "^3.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
        "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "startbootstrap-blog-home": "^4.2.1"
    }
}
```

5. Ran `yarn install`.
6. Added `assets/js/adminlte.js` with `require('../../vendor/kevinpapst/adminlte-bundle/Resources/assets/admin-lte');`
7. Ran `yarn encore dev`

The problem now is, the layout doesn't render properly at all. Like, it has the right text from the layout but it doesn't show the layout properly (see the attached screen).

[See the problem with the layout here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n0rw.png)

The template rendered in my controller function of the route contains only this:

`{% extends 'admincp/base.html.twig' %}`

The `admincp/base.html.twig` contains this:

```
{% extends '@AdminLTE/layout/default-layout.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/adminlte.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('build/adminlte.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

It doesn't throw an error or anything but it doesn't work either. It requests and gets the CSS and JS correctly.

(in case more information is needed, kindly ask and I'll provide it).

Comment: Well you should ask the author for support maybe.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser's developer tools, e.g. missing scripts/stylesheets in the network tab or js errors in the console that look like they are related?

Comment: Instead of ussing the `asset` helper you might want to use the ones provided by the encore bundle: `encore_entry_script_tags('adminlete')` and `encore_entry_link_tags('adminlete')` as your encore build might produce multiple files, instead of just one `build/adminlte.css` and `build/adminlte.js`

Comment: I saw other files and I had to add other files to my layout. The only thing is font awesome still doesn't work but I had to add the `vendors~` js and css files and it worked.